# How can I manage a "GET" HTTP request over time without deleting the previous result?

Tags: database, join, powerquery

I am currently using a REST API to retreive data from an app allowing us to manage a logistic warehouse. I am using Power Query for this.

The data : All the activity of trucks loading/unloading at the warehouse (timestamp of each steps in the physical flow from registration to departure, location, timestamp last modification). Each truck is identify with a unique "VisitorID".

For now, I am extracting all the visitors in the app for each refresh.
I have a paginated GET request and it is working fine but, it is not optimised and in a near future I will have a lot of pages in my dataset and it won't be manageable with the API's rate limits.

I am trying to use a parameter of the request called "updatedSince". If provided, only visitors that have been created or have changed since the given datetime are returned.

Here is an example of the data model that I imagined :

[Schema on first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2U6.png)

Unfortunatly, If I keep it that way, I won't be able to increment the historicalData table with the results of UpdatedData Table. I need to make historicalData dynamic and make it like FinalData table.

Here is the schema for the refresh :

[Schema on refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPBmV.png)

How can I implement this solution ? Power Query is able to manage that ?

Comment: depending of your source and if you are on a premium environment you could setup "incremental refresh" but PQ is by design not very good in storing data. If you need to keep a large history it would be better to set a DB layer before your PBI.